# How do you add Promoted Links to the Sites Page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I removed all the promoted links on the Sites page on Office 365's SharePoint Online.

Is there a way to activate the default links again?

Comment: Did you remove the webpart from a page, or the app from a Site Contents page?

Comment: I don't think I did either.  If you know the default page I'm talking about (something like this: https://domain-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_domain/_layouts/15/touchapp.aspx?Mode=Sites&Page=FollowedSites), I simply removed all the links while managing promoted links.

Comment: So you removed all the promoted links by accident? The standard way of editing the promoted links is using a default quick edit (excel view) and hence they should be in your recycle bin. Or the site collection administrator recycle bin.

Comment: Yeah. But is it the same for the Office 365 Sites page?  Can you normally edit these links from a list? Can you edit these pages/web parts in the browser normally?

Comment: Yeah, i guess the promoted links are the same in o365, and administrated the same way. The promoted links is a list with a custom view.

Comment: Ok. I cant seem to find it. Maybe it's just a issue of the Office 365 subscription level we have.  This is the normal way to do it apparently (http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/manage-my-site-settings-for-sharepoint-online-HA102772278.aspx#_Toc364700636), but the P1 Office 365 Plan does not have access to the SharePoint Admin Center